# Print special character jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to change the following string

> Hello Mr ABC

to read:

> `Hello "Mr ABC"`.

The string `Mr ABC` contains a special/unprintable character " ".

P.S: where can I see related documents?

Comment: first please try to fix your grammar, your question is incomprehensible. also show us some code of what you tried.

Comment: you want to escape them with a \ which tells javascript to treat them as literal characters instead of as `"`

Comment: try with `Hello \"Mr ABC\"`

Comment: @nonchip. I'm so sorry, My english skill is bad. I will try my best.

Comment: @yuvi and Himanshu. I done it. thank all. good luck.

Comment: didn't mean to offend, it's just I didn't get anything of what you want to ask :D

Comment: @GiangDHN, did either of our responses below help you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can escape special characters by preceding them with a backslash (`\`). So the double-quotation mark would be `\"`, as in `Hello \"Mr ABC\"`.

The docs you seek are at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Using_special_characters_in_strings.

Of course, the double-quote marks wouldn't be a problem if they're in a single-quote–defined string (as would be convention in JavaScript and jQuery, but not in HTML): `'Hello "Mr ABC"'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery also. Just need to replace your string with "str" variable.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var str = "Hello Mr ABC"; // replace your string
     var newStr = str.substr(0,5)+' "'+$.trim(str.substr(5,str.length-1))+'"';
     alert(newStr);
    });
```

Comment: why in the world do you need jQuery?